# New Beamer Version: Transparent Title Page Boxes

Tags: beamer

Consider the following file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=red}
\setbeamercolor{author}{bg=yellow}
\setbeamercolor{date}{bg=}
\setbeamercolor{institute}{fg=red,bg=green}

\title{TitelTitelTitel}
\author{meiermueller}
\institute{Institute}
\date{lalala}

\begin{document}
 \usebackgroundtemplate{\color{blue}\rule{20cm}{15cm}} 

 \begin{frame}
   \titlepage
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

On one of my computers (using MiKTeX 2.9 and `beamer 2015/01/05 3.36`), the result is the following:

[image]

Note how, in particular, the `date` box has a transparent background

On my other computer, I installed a new MiKTeX version (2.9.6800), including `beamer 2018/09/02 v3.52`, and get this:

[image]

Here, the `date` field has a white background, and I cannot seem to get it to be transparent.

Apparently, the difference has some relation to the beamer version, or maybe some other change in the new MiKTeX version. 
But what ist the reason, and how do I get transparent backgrounds?

Comment: With `2018/09/06 v3.53` on a fully updated TL2018 I do get the same output as in your first screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/594db5d8f027c781c4ecc2b38907e04d2b16f043

Please update to beamer v.3.53 (or higher) or (as a temporary workaround) place the file https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/master/base/beamerbasecolor.sty in your working directory.